# Reference request: $K$-theoretic wrong-way map for a boundary inclusion

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, cohomology, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Let $W$ be a compact manifold with boundary. Let $i:\partial W\hookrightarrow W$ be the natural inclusion. We have a long exact sequence in complex $K$-theory:
$$\ldots\to K^*(\partial W)\xrightarrow{d} K^{*+1}(W,\partial W)\xrightarrow{j^*}K^{*+1}(W)\to\ldots,$$
where $j^*$ is induced by the inclusion $j:(W,\emptyset)\hookrightarrow(W,\partial W)$.

Let us assume that $W$ is also spin$^c$. Then we have in addition a wrong-way (Gysin) map
$$i_!:K^*(\partial W)\to K^{*+1}(W)$$
defined via the Thom isomorphism.

It seems from the answers and comments to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369307/does-the-gysin-map-in-k-theory-respect-bordism/369730?noredirect=1#comment933959_369730), that $i_!=j^*\circ d$ (in particular equal to zero).

**Question:** Is there is a reference containing a discussion of this seemingly basic result?